# PayPal Donate button in React: Donate SDK or Checkout SDK integration?

Tags: reactjs, paypal

The official NPM package @paypal/react-paypal-js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js only supports buttons that require client_id, I have not been able to find anything that simplifies the implementation of Donate button. PayPal provides only this HTML code below on the Donate button documentation. Please let me know if anyone has had a similar experience and how did you manage to implement it properly in React/Gatsby.

```html
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- Ensures optimal rendering on mobile devices. -->
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> <!-- Optimal Internet Explorer compatibility -->
</head>

<body>
 <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/donate/sdk/donate-sdk.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>

<body>
 <div id="paypal-donate-button-container"></div>

  <script>
   PayPal.Donation.Button({
       env: 'sandbox',
       hosted_button_id: 'YOUR_SANDBOX_HOSTED_BUTTON_ID',
       // business: 'YOUR_EMAIL_OR_PAYERID',
       image: {
           src: 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif',
           title: 'PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!',
           alt: 'Donate with PayPal button'
       },
       onComplete: function (params) {
           // Your onComplete handler
       },
   }).render('#paypal-donate-button-container');
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to use the **Donate SDK** HTML/JS from react.

1. Configure the app to load the SDK script at page load time (typically as part of the page's `<head>`). The JS to render the button can then be run/outputted whenever as part of a component.
2. [Insert the script element into the DOM *after* page load and once loaded render buttons with a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66307168/paypal-not-defined-when-customizing-own-src-for-script-tag). This can all be placed in a React component's `useEffect` or similar. The linked example using `loadAsync` is for the Checkout SDK, but that's easily swapped out for Donate SDK code.

---

You can use the Donate SDK with a `hosted_button_id` as you mentioned (created at https://www.paypal.com/buttons (live) or [www.sandbox.paypal.com/buttons](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/buttons)) -- or alternatively, instead of a hosted button id just pass a `business` parameter with either the receiving account's PayPal email address or (ideally) its [PayPal Merchant ID](https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/aboutBusiness) (since that will never change whereas an email can be removed from the account and no longer point to it)

---

Later edit: Note that the Donate SDK is separate from simply relabeling a normal PayPal Checkout SDK button with the text "Donate", which can be done [per the react-paypal-js storybook example](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--donate), as another answer mentioned. The issue with this approach is after clicking the button it will look like a standard PayPal checkout, not a donation-specific flow...

Using the actual Donate SDK instead results in a more tailored donor flow where they can select any amount in the large input, and even check an option to make their donation recurring:

[image]

Comment: I am getting Uncaught Error: Request listener already exists for zoid_allow_delegate_donate_checkout on domain * for wildcard when I update my react app and the app re-renders

Comment: ignore it or don't load the SDK script on any page more than once

Comment: How can I ignore it or make sure the script is only loaded once? Currently I am defining it inside UseEffect with [] dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to the React SDK team and they said it actually comes with support for donate out of the box and there is an example in [their storybook](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--donate). Here's the relevant code. If you use this approach you shouldn't need `hosted_button_id`:

```
<PayPalButtons
  fundingSource="paypal"
  style={{
    layout: "vertical",
    label: "donate"
  }}
  createOrder={(data, actions) => {
    return actions.order
      .create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
              value: "2",
              currency_code: "USD",
            },
            items: [{
                name: "donation-example",
                quantity: "1",
                unit_amount: {
                  currency_code: "USD",
                  value: "2",
                },
                category: "DONATION",
            }],
        }],
      })
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: That doesn't use the Donate SDK, it's a regular PayPal Checkout button with the text label "Donate" added within the button -- that's all. It gives a different customer experience than the donation-specific one of the Donate SDK.  For instance, there will be no option to choose their own amount or make it recurring.

Comment: @PrestonPHX right, so you can add a basic donate button with the react sdk, but if you want some of the cooler features of the donate SDK you have to wrap it in `useEffect` or something. I'll try to throw together a working example of that tomorrow to highlight the different benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I didn't see how exactly the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66308051) could work with React because of the reference error: `PayPal.Donation.Button` is undefined, and the code wouldn't compile if I tried using it as a function.

I looked into appending the whole script tag as a string (dangerouslySetInnerHTML) and found this blog post to be a great explanation: [Render dangerous content with React.](https://dev.to/christo_pr/render-dangerous-content-with-react-2j7j) The author makes a pretty cool use of [document.Range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) in order to solve the problem of executing scripts inside html. He has also published his solution as a small package: [dangerously-set-html-content.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dangerously-set-html-content)

I gave it a try in my Gatsby project. First thing I'm adding the Donate SDK script tag on the body in `gatsby-srr.js` in order to fetch the JapaScript on page load:

```
exports.onRenderBody = ({setPreBodyComponents}) => {
    setPreBodyComponents(
        <script key={0} src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/donate/sdk/donate-sdk.js" charSet="UTF-8"/>
    )
}
```

(I need the bizarre-looking `key` attribute to avoid errors when html.js is compiled. Once it's merged, the attribute is removed)

And then in the component I'm setting the script as a string:

```
import React from 'react'
import InnerHTML from 'dangerously-set-html-content'
const html = `
    <div id="donate-button-container">
        <div id="donate-button">
            <script>
                PayPal.Donation.Button({
                    ...
                }}).render('#donate-button')
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
`
function MyComponent() {
    return (
       <InnerHTML html={html} />
    )
}
```

You can have a look at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/christo-pr/dangerously-set-html-content/blob/main/libs/dangerously-set-html-content/src/lib/dangerously-set-html-content.tsx) of the package for the explanation of how `useEffect` and `useRef` hooks are used, and for some usage examples.

Answer (score 0):

In NextJS I did this (irrelevant lines removed)

1. in `_document.js`:

```
export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/donate/sdk/donate-sdk.js" defer/>
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

2. component where I wanted the button:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function Donate() {
  const [doPaypal, setDoPaypal] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setDoPaypal(true);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {
        doPaypal && 
        <div id="donate-button-container">
        <div id="donate-button"></div>
          <Script id="donate-button-script">
            {`
            PayPal.Donation.Button({
              env:'production',
              hosted_button_id:'${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_HOSTED_BUTTON_ID}',
              image: {
                src:'https://whatever/paypal-donate.png',
                alt:'Donate with PayPal button', 
                title:'PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!',
              }
            }).render('#donate-button');
          `}
        </Script>
        </div>
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

A similar approach will work in vanilla React, but the thing here is that NextJS provides the `<Script>` component which is ideal rather than using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML()`. Also note the use of the environment to store your PayPal button ID; this must be a visible on the client-side hence using the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix.